# Regular Expression - Password Validation is not working

Tags: regex, validation

I have to validate the password using regex.
The password rule is like at least 1 uppercase and at least 2 numeric.

It works fine except if the character comes at the end of the string.

The regular expression which i am using is

```
"^(?=.*\d.{2})(?=.*[A-Z].{1})(?=.*[@#$%^&+=].{2}).{8,12}$"
```

Rules:

- minimum length = 8
- minimum uppercase  = 1
- minimum numeric = 2
- minimum special character = 1

It works for `Test123$$`, `Test$123`, `TEST123$s`, `Test123$1`, `Test12$3` but it fails if the character specified comes at the end of the string like `Test123$`, `Test$a12`, `Test12aa@`, `123aa@@T`.

Please let me know if there is any fix for this.

Comment: Your regex works only for `Test$123`.

Comment: What happens if you try 123$$Test? I suspect it will fail. I am not so sure using a regular expression is the best tool for this purpose.

Comment: @whatsisname in this case it is not the best, but it will work. Check my regex: your string successfully passes.

Answer (score 2):

In your regex I see some problems:

- `(?=.*\d.{2})` - why the second `.`, you can't check for two occurrences with `{2}`, because that assumes that they are nearby ... *Test1$2$3* should be allowed, too ...
- `(?=.*[A-Z].{1})` - why the second `.`
- `(?=.*[@#$%^&+=].{2})` - and again, why the second `.`, why do you check for 2 occurrences? Spec says one special char.
- (And you check for a maximum of 12 chars, what is not specified, too)

Try

```
"^(?=.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).{8,12}$"
```

which passes:

```
Debug.Assert( regex.IsMatch( "Test123$" ) );
Debug.Assert( regex.IsMatch( "Test123$$" ) );
Debug.Assert( regex.IsMatch( "$Test1$2" ) );   // two numbers, not following
Debug.Assert( regex.IsMatch( "Test$123" ) );
Debug.Assert( !regex.IsMatch( "Test12$" ) );   // 7 chars
Debug.Assert( !regex.IsMatch( "Test12345" ) ); // no special char
Debug.Assert( !regex.IsMatch( "Test$$$$" ) );  // no number
Debug.Assert( !regex.IsMatch( "Test$3$$" ) );  // only one number
Debug.Assert( !regex.IsMatch( "test12$$" ) );  // no upper case
```

Comment: Why are you using `{1}` quantifier?

Comment: @SilentGhost - exactly what I was going to ask.

Comment: @SilentGhost, @GalacticCowboy: the source of all foolness: copy & paste :) I modified the original regex ... will edit, thx for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you use `(atom).{length}` and length is applied to `.`, not to `atom`. You should use `(atom){length}`. And, secondly, `\d{2}` is not «minimum numeric: 2». It is «2 consequent digits». «Minimum numeric: 2» looks like this: `.*\d.*\d`, so the full regex (note that `(atom){1}` and `(atom)` are the same regexes):

```
^(?=.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%\^&+=]).{8,12}$
```

And, please, replace `{8,12}` with `{8,}`: you should not forbid users to enter long passwords.

Comment: Except where "long" means that it causes other issues.  But yeah, there's no reason not to allow a 20-30 character password.  If you're properly salting/hashing your passwords, length should not be an issue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your list of requirements does not specify a regular language. Thus it will be difficult (if not impossible) to match using a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot make a finite state machine for this, so (unless there's something different about regexes in practice than in theory) you won't be able to find a regex for this.

mainly, because it involves counting, which requires "memory" which is something a finite state machine doesn't have.

edit:  apparently, there have been advances in DFA "technology".  see comments to this post.

Comment: Many flavors of regex support the concepts of "backtracking" and "zero-width assertions", which are precisely what the OP wants.  The FSA is more complex, but it's not impossible.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974210/does-lookaround-affect-which-languages-can-be-matched-by-regular-expressions.

Answer (score 0):

While you're not saying what flavour of regex you're using, I'd suggest the following approach, which —if not most efficient— is more readable and maintainable (using Python only for example):

```
>>> import string
>>> def valid(s):
    return 8 <= len(s) <= 12 and \
           any(c in string.ascii_uppercase for c in s) and \
           sum(c in string.digits for c in s) >= 2 and \
           any(c in string.punctuation for c in s)

>>> valid('abcdefA')
False
>>> valid('123aa@@T')
True
>>> valid('Test123$')
True
>>> valid('Test123_')
True
```