# What are the theoretical implications of unbounded lookbehind?

Tags: .net, regex, theory, finite-automata, regular-language

Most languages allow fixed-length or finite-length lookbehind.  One notable exception is .NET, which allows the use of the * operator.

However, .NET regexs can already recognize balanced parentheses using named capture, which is not a regular language.  Are regexs still regular with * in lookbehind?  Extended answers for subexpressions other than * (for example, additional lookaround!) would also be appreciated.

tl;dr: Do regexs stay regular with * in lookbehind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer here: [Does lookaround affect which languages can be matched by regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974210/does-lookaround-affect-which-languages-can-be-matched-by-regular-expressions/2991587#2991587) can be extended to prove that adding * in lookbehind (or even nesting such lookbehinds and lookaheads) does not affect the 'regularness' of the expressions. I haven't put more thought into it though.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

.NET's unbounded lookbehind is merely a refinement of an already non-regular feature: fixed, finite or infinite, lookbehinds have no place in a regular grammar.  Nor do lookaheads, capturing groups, backreferences, reluctant quantifiers, possessive quantifiers, atomic groups, conditionals, word boundaries, anchors...

If we had to limit ourselves to theoretically-pure regular expressions, 99.9% of current regex users would have no use for them.  Asking if a feature is "regular" is a waste of breath; is it *useful*?  That's all that matters.

Comment: -1 Many of the features you just listed (including lookaround) are perfectly regular. Also calling the question a waste of breath is a) rude and b) wrong as the regularness of a regular expression has practical implications: there are some things you can do with regular regular expressions, that you can't do with irregular regular expressions. For example: find their intersection.

Comment: These features are not in the traditional formulation of regular expressions, but they are still regular.  For anyone that reads this question at some later time:
Lookaheads (infinite-length), reluctant quantifiers, possessive quantifiers, atomic groups, word boundries, and anchors are regular.
Capturing groups are essentially irrelevant.
Backreferences, given capturing groups, are non-regular.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are closed under intersection.  Add a new symbol & and rewrite the lookbehind:
A(?<B)C as 
(?:AC&.*BC), and we get that lookbehind is regular.

B can include clearly use anything that doesn't go past the A/C boundry.  That is, anything except lookahead.  What happens if lookbehind may use lookahead, or vice-versa?  Start work on .*BC .  You're still fine.

So, regular expressions could really add in intersection and infinite-length lookaround (which can include more lookaround to any depth) and it would still be just as efficient.