# Why is this regex not matching like the other?

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the inner-most content between `@@BOKeyword-` and `-End@@` in the following example:

```
@@BOKeyword-Here is@@BOKeyword-I want to match this!-End@@stuff-End@@
```

So my match would be: `I want to match this!` I'm using the following regex: `@@BOKeyword-([^@@BOKeyword--End@@]*)-End@@`

However, this doesn't match at all. I developed this based on this example which I derived from [a previous question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13260947/971592):

```
AC I want to match this! BD I don't want to match this! AC I want to match this! BD I don't want to match this! BD
```

Using the regex: `AC([^ACBD]*)BD`

And this works as expected. I think I'm misunderstanding how this works. Any tips would be appreciated! Thanks!

**Note:** I'm running this in Java.

Comment: `[]` groups match (positively or negatively) one character at a time.  Not entire strings.  So `[^ABCD]` actually means a single character that is not A,B,C or D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your regex engine support `lookaround`, you can try this:

```
(?<=@@BOKeyword-).((?<!@@BOKeyword-).(?!-End@@))*.(?=-End@@)
```

- the first `DOT` matches start character: `I`
- the middle `DOT` matches characters not surrounded by your delimiters: `·want·to·match·this`
- the last `DOT` matches end character: `!`

---

There are 2 cases not cover (only one/zero character in between):

```
(?<=@@BOKeyword-).?(?=-End@@)
```

---

It's pretty hard to combine these two regex. Another way is:

- replace your delimiters with `{`/`}` (or other single character pair)
- write a simpler regex to match